# R and gganimate: How to change the title

Tags: r, gganimate

Good morning SO community,
I have the following snippet of code:

```
library( animation )
library( dplyr )    
library( gganimate )
library( ggplot2 )

someData = data.frame( years = seq( -5000, 1000, by = 100 ) ) %>%
mutate( values = sample( 1:20, length( years ), replace = TRUE ),
      label = ifelse( years < 0, paste0( abs( years ), ' B.C.E.' ), years ) )

chart = ggplot( someData ) + 
geom_line( aes( x = years, y = values, frame = years, cumulative = TRUE ) ) +
ggtitle( 'Year:  ' )

gganimate( chart, interval = .2 )
```

This way, the years appear in the title of the plot (numerically ordered).
Is there a way to put the `label` values - in the same order they appear in the data frame - instead?

My first try was to use `frame = label` in the aesthetics of `geom_line` but the labels appeared in alphabetical order. So, I tried to change the levels order through:

```
someData$label = factor( someData$label, levels = someData$label, order = TRUE )
```

but this gave me the following error:

```
Error in frame_vec == f : comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
Incompatible methods ("Ops.ordered", "Ops.factor") for "=="
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a pending [pull request](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate/pull/20) concerning this functionality, but it hasn't been merged into the original repo yet. In the meantime, you could install the modified package using `devtools::install_github("nteetor/gganimate")`, and then you can do:

```
gg_animate(chart, title_frame = ~ with(someData, label[years == .]))
```

Comment: Thanks @mtoto. Unfortunately your fix is not working to me. First, I have to write something like: `gg_animate(chart, title_frame = ~ someData$label[.])` to not get the following error: `Error: could not create frame title, object 'label' not found`. Then, it puts the correct label just for the first frame (5000 B.C.E.): it keeps unchanged till the 0 label (not shown in the title) and then it shows `NA`. There is also an issue with the `ggtitle` and `label`instructions as you prepend a text (e.g. 'Years:') to the `frame` value: it eventually ignores it.

Comment: Could the above issues be somehow related to the following warning: `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?` ?. Thank you

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. And modifying it this way: `title_frame = ~ paste0( 'Year: ', with( someData, label[ years == . ] ) )`, it is possible to have a more meaningful title.